# OpenGL Draw Points with indeces

Tags: opengl, glut

I was trying to draw a single point at 0,0 but my screen turns white and stops responding.

Can someone look into the code and see where I am making a mistake?

```
float *vertices;
GLubyte *pindices;
int width, height;

GLuint vboHandlePoints[1];
GLuint indexVBOPoints;

int numberOfPoints;
GLuint buf;

void initVboPoints(){

    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if (err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboHandlePoints[0]);   // create a VBO handle
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandlePoints[0]);   // bind the handle to the current VBO 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1 * 2 * 4, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // allocate space and copy the data over
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   // clean up 

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexVBOPoints);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOPoints);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte)*1 * 2, pindices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);  //clean up 


}
void display(){
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);

    glPointSize(5);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandlePoints[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOPoints);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);// 2-dimension

    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (char*)NULL + 0);
}

void initializeGlut(int argc, char** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    width = 400;
    height = 400;
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("Bhavya's Program");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

}

void initNormal(){
    vertices = new float[2];
    pindices = new GLubyte[1];
    vertices[0] = 0;
    vertices[1] = 0;
    pindices[0] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    initNormal();
    initializeGlut(argc, argv);
    initVboPoints();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` bound at the time of the `glVertexPointer` call. All of the `gl*Pointer` functions reference the *currently* bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, the buffer name becomes part of the pointer. That way, you can source each attribute from a different VBO. The `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is totally irrelevant for the `glDraw*` family of functions.

Since you use deprecated legacy GL, binding VBO 0 is still valid, and your pointer references the client memory. So your application is likely to just crash because you told the GL to [read the data at memory address 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Causes)...

Comment: I moved it down after the binding, but didn't helped, the output screen still becomes white and does not produce any point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `glFlush();` is required